# SQL Server as Prerequisite in VS Setup Project error in Windows Vista

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, setup-project, prerequisites

I'm having problems installing SQL Server as prerequisite on my Visual Studio Setup application on Windows Vista.
I' able to install it if I install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) and then run the setup, but that's not what I need because I need that the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) be installed without user interaction. I have already put the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) as prerequisite, and now it's being installed before SQL Server but the same error occurs during SQL Server Installation. 
The interesting is that if in Windows XP the Setup runs  without problems.

> Activation context generation failed
>   for ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe"".
>   Dependent Assembly
>   Microsoft.VC80.ATL,processorArchitecture=""x86"",publicKeyToken=""1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"",type=""win32"",
>   version=""8.0.50608.0"" could not be
>   found. Please use sxstrace.exe for
>   detailed diagnosis.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Paulo

Comment: This sounds like it would be UAC related to me.  If you right click on the setup and Run As Administrator does it have this same problem installing under Administrative priviledges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved this issue the problem is that SQL Server depends on Visual C++ 2005 and not Visual C++ 2008, I have putted this package as prerequisite and it works well.

Many thanks,
Paulo